# PDF gets stuck when opening through iframe using window.open()

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, window.open

I am trying to open PDF that I am receiving as a string in base64 format in a new tab. It opens in a new window without any content but when I do "inspect element" on the page, I get the PDF perfectly fine.

Here is my code -

```
var pdfWindow = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(payload)+"'></iframe>");
```

Also, I want to open a PDF in a new tab, not in a new window. When opening in a new window, the PDF opens perfectly fine.

To open in new window, I use this code -

```
let pdfWindow = window.open("", '_blank', 'dependent=yes,locationbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,resizable,screenX=50,screenY=50,width=850,height=800')
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(payload)+"'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but could helpful for others:
The problem is with the iframe width and height tags. Instead of using percentages, use defined pixels. This will resolve the issue.

```
<iframe width='600px' height='600px' ...> </iframe>
```